# why am I receiving this error == Reverse for 'download_done' not found. 'download_done' is not a valid view function or pattern name

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to create a youtube downloader but when I'm trying to download it gives this error

> Reverse for 'download_done' not found. 'download_done' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

I have compared the app name and its corresponding, I have also checked the HTML file it looks okay

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from pytube import YouTube
import os

# Create your views here.
def youtubedownloader(request):
    return render(request, 'youtube_downloader.html')

def download(request):
    global url
    url = request.GET.get('url')
    yt = YouTube(url)
    video = []
    video = yt.streams.filter(progressive=True).all()
    embed_link = url.replace("watch?v=", "embed/")
    Title = yt.title
    context = {'video': video, 'embed': embed_link, 'title': Title}


    return render(request, 'download.html', context)


def download_done(request, resolution):
    global url
    homedir = os.path.expanduser("~")
    dirs = homedir + '/Downloads'
    if request.method == "POST":
        YouTube(url).streams.get_by_resolution(resolution).download(dirs)
        return render(request, 'download_done.html')
    else:
        return render(request, 'errorrrr.html')
```

urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from .views import youtubedownloader, download, download_done

app_name = 'yt_downloader'


urlpatterns = [
    path('youtube_downloader/', youtubedownloader, name='youtube downloader'),
    path('youtube_downloader/download/', download, name='download  video'),
    path('download/<resolution>/', download_done, name='download  done')
    ]
```

download.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}

<div class="container">
<h1> Title : {{title}} </h1>
    <div class=" mt-5 embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
  <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src={{embed}} allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>

<table class="table">
  <thead class="thead-light">
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Size</th>
      <th scope="col">Type</th>
      <th scope="col">Quality</th>
      <th scope="col">Download</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  {% for j in video %}
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th> {{j.filesize}}</th>
      <td>{{j.type}}</td>
      <td>{{j.resolution}}</td>
      <td><form action="{% url 'yt_downloader:download_done' j.resolution %}" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Download">

      </form>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  {% endfor %}
</table>
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the url path name to **`download_done`**, like the following:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('youtube_downloader/', youtubedownloader, name='youtube_downloader'),
    path('youtube_downloader/download/', download, name='download_video'),
    path('download/<resolution>/', download_done, name='download_done')
]
```